# I have question About Bluetooth Connectivity and disconnectivity from Setting screen in iPhone

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

If i have bluetooth headphone connected from setting screen and now in my calling application call is ongoing, and in background i will disconnect headphone and then come to my application but i didn't get any event of core bluetooth that can identify headset is connected or disconnected.

So any one can help me about this scenario. if you have any question you can ask me.

Comment: Does your app have any reference to the peripheral (headphones)? Unless you have connected the peripheral through your app's instance of `CBCentralManager` or have a reference to them using `retrievePeripherals`, your app will have no way to listen for changes.

Comment: No, peripheral is doesn't connect through my application. it's directly connected from Setting App iPhone. So i didn't get any listen for connectivity or dis-connectivity.

Comment: Then you will never be notified if you do not connect the device in the app or get a reference to it. It would do you good to [read the best practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html) when dealing with a peripheral.